# Why doesn't Git use more modern SHA?

Tags: git, cryptography, sha

I read about that Git uses SHA-1 digest as an ID for a revision.  Why does it not use a more modern version of SHA?

Comment: Performance is the only reason I can think of, SHA-1 is faster than SHA-2. Personally I consider it a bad decision, since SHA-1's collision resistance is rather weak.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392365/how-would-git-handle-a-sha-1-collision-on-a-blob - not an exact match, but covers similar ground

Comment: We can't really know what Linus Torvalds was thinking when he decided this.

Comment: This was discussed on the git mailing list in 2006. See [the whole thread](http://marc.info/?t=115670140400001&r=1&w=2).

To summarize, Linus said back then that SHA-1 only needed to be unique enough so collisions don't occur, which it is. SHA-1 is not a security feature for git.

"Anybody who just blindly accepts data from untrusted sources is screwed in so many other ways that the hash attack simply isn't even on the radar." -- [Linus](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=115679088919477&w=2)

Comment: Update: SHA-1 collisions now in the wild https://shattered.it/

Comment: Q1 2018: this effort to support an alternative SHA is underway: see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47838703/6309)

Comment: Q3 2018, with git 2.19, the choice has been made: it will be SHA-256. See [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47838703/6309).

Comment: I think it's simply a design mistake. It is now being corrected. For a long time, certain Git developers pretended that SHA1 was fine even after collisions had been found.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

> Why does it not use a more modern version of SHA?

Dec. 2017: It will. And Git 2.16 (Q1 2018) is the first release to illustrate and implement that intent.

Note: see Git 2.19 below: it will be **SHA-256**.

Git 2.16 will propose an infrastructure to define what hash function is used in Git, and will start an effort to plumb that throughout various codepaths.

See [commit c250e02](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c250e02e2c6de8c116f4320a48ce44bbdb43015c) (28 Nov 2017) by [Ramsay Jones (``)](https://github.com/).
See [commit eb0ccfd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb0ccfd7f5ce1765ada74abf272f002e1e34d1e4), [commit 78a6766](https://github.com/git/git/commit/78a6766802ef32b82e6062e8e6ac5621894cc4a2), [commit f50e766](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f50e766b7b3dd02fc44ff7d4339c6f62e70fbf60), [commit abade65](https://github.com/git/git/commit/abade65b79bdf505603b3699a2f9de75b318aa6e) (12 Nov 2017) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 721cc43](https://github.com/git/git/commit/721cc4314cb593e799213ad5f926a1e9fc5779b0), 13 Dec 2017)</sup>

---

> ### Add structure representing hash algorithm

> Since in the future we want to support an additional hash algorithm, add **[a structure that represents a hash algorithm and all the data that must go along with it](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f50e766b7b3dd02fc44ff7d4339c6f62e70fbf60/hash.h#L37-L71)**.
> Add a [constant to allow easy enumeration of hash algorithms](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f50e766b7b3dd02fc44ff7d4339c6f62e70fbf60/hash.h#L30-L31).
> Implement [function `typedefs`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f50e766b7b3dd02fc44ff7d4339c6f62e70fbf60/hash.h#L33-L35) to create an abstract API that can be used by any hash algorithm, and wrappers for the existing SHA1 functions that conform to this API.
>
> Expose a [value for hex size as well as binary size](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f50e766b7b3dd02fc44ff7d4339c6f62e70fbf60/hash.h#L47-L54).
> While one will always be twice the other, the two values are both used extremely
> commonly throughout the codebase and providing both leads to improved readability.
>
> Don't include an entry in the hash algorithm structure for the null object ID.
> As this value is all zeros, any suitably sized all-zero object ID can be used, and there's no need to store a given one on a per-hash basis.
>
> The current hash function transition plan envisions a time when we will accept input from the user that might be in SHA-1 or in the NewHash format.
> Since we cannot know which the user has provided, add a **[constant representing the unknown algorithm](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f50e766b7b3dd02fc44ff7d4339c6f62e70fbf60/hash.h#L26-L27)** to allow us to indicate that we must look the correct value up.

---

> ### Integrate hash algorithm support with repo setup

> In future versions of Git, we plan to support an additional hash
> algorithm.
> Integrate the enumeration of hash algorithms with repository setup, and **store a pointer to the enumerated data in struct repository**.
> Of course, **[we currently only support SHA-1, so hard-code this value in
> `read_repository_format`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/78a6766802ef32b82e6062e8e6ac5621894cc4a2/setup.c#L486-L491)**.
> In the future, we'll enumerate this value from the configuration.
>
> Add [a constant, **`the_hash_algo`**](https://github.com/git/git/blob/78a6766802ef32b82e6062e8e6ac5621894cc4a2/cache.h#L81), which points to the `hash_algo` structure pointer in the repository global.
> Note that this is the hash which is used to serialize data to disk, not the hash which is used to display items to the user.
> The transition plan anticipates that these may be different.
> We can add an additional element in the future (say, `ui_hash_algo`) to provide for this case.

---

Update August 2018, for Git 2.19 (Q3 2018), Git seems to pick **SHA-256** as NewHash.

See [commit 0ed8d8d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ed8d8da374f648764758f13038ca93af87ab800) (04 Aug 2018) by [Jonathan Nieder (`artagnon`)](https://github.com/artagnon).
See [commit 13f5e09](https://github.com/git/git/commit/13f5e0982121ea1f1fc1b94f1e559bfb23aa0a16) (25 Jul 2018) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 34f2297](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34f229790dcc7c7dc61bc37532f88fca39e36de2), 20 Aug 2018)</sup>

> ### [doc `hash-function-transition`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0ed8d8da374f648764758f13038ca93af87ab800/Documentation/technical/hash-function-transition.txt): pick SHA-256 as NewHash

> From a security perspective, it seems that SHA-256, BLAKE2, SHA3-256, K12, and so on are all believed to have similar security properties.
> All are good options from a security point of view.
>
> SHA-256 has a number of advantages:
>
> - It has been around for a while, is widely used, and is supported by just about every single crypto library (OpenSSL, mbedTLS, CryptoNG, SecureTransport, etc).
> - When you compare against SHA1DC, most vectorized SHA-256 implementations are indeed faster, even without acceleration.
> - If we're doing signatures with OpenPGP (or even, I suppose, CMS), we're going to be using SHA-2, so it doesn't make sense to have our security depend on two separate algorithms when either one of them alone could break the security when we could just depend on one.
>
> **So SHA-256 it is**.
> Update the hash-function-transition design doc to say so.
>
> After this patch, there are no remaining instances of the string
> "`NewHash`", except for an unrelated use from 2008 as [a variable name in `t/t9700/test.pl`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0ed8d8da374f648764758f13038ca93af87ab800/t/t9700/test.pl#L96-L99).

---

You can see this transition to SHA 256 in progress with Git 2.20 (Q4 2018):

See [commit 0d7c419](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d7c419a94b7524ac854d5a6002b7541abab4f12), [commit dda6346](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dda634687717fd8aafd54cae9ae3d9b2902e276e), [commit eccb5a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eccb5a5f3d8d49ec9b4645aac94bffb7e504f10f), [commit 93eb00f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93eb00f719a2d36d31a4ba7b6eeae9f6302314e9), [commit d8a3a69](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d8a3a690204ec8583b536e562d46632cae5cfe03), [commit fbd0e37](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fbd0e37cde633221d5b3ca239f26cb7d005da5c8), [commit f690b6b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f690b6b03049e8f564aa0a1abbde5ec0731c5774), [commit 49d1660](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49d166081bb5ddefa57fd97fd517449264ee5246), [commit 268babd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/268babd6fb06cfb897d48f7a9adb4828f5f6b45f), [commit fa13080](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa130802d9ccde50e4097b2b1c5324990be3ffb4), [commit 7b5e614](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b5e614e2acc2f4e6b2f1ea4eb93dd430d350abd), [commit 58ce21b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/58ce21b819e582db2a96d170fdd24d3f7bc6c4d0), [commit 2f0c9e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2f0c9e9a9bbe8015da2c0838f3051c0a336dee26), [commit 825544a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/825544a3511c679ea1b51ffaf1cd565e8ed035ec) (15 Oct 2018) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
See [commit 6afedba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6afedba8c97b5a8463e45ff801218433f8392d5d) (15 Oct 2018) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d829d49](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d829d491eebddc2eefcaa9279ac4b67c7eefbd52), 30 Oct 2018)</sup>

> ### replace hard-coded constants

> Replace several 40-based constants with references to `GIT_MAX_HEXSZ` or
> `the_hash_algo`, as appropriate.
> Convert all uses of the `GIT_SHA1_HEXSZ` to use `the_hash_algo` so that they
> are appropriate for any given hash length.
> Instead of using a hard-coded constant for the size of a hex object ID,
> switch to use the computed pointer from `parse_oid_hex` that points after
> the parsed object ID.

`GIT_SHA1_HEXSZ` is further remove/replaced with Git 2.22 (Q2 2019) and [commit d4e568b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d4e568b2a31d7b2fe45dac9165bb077b570fc96a).

---

That transition continues with Git 2.21 (Q1 2019), which adds sha-256 hash and plug it through the code to allow building Git with the "NewHash".

See [commit 4b4e291](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4b4e2918099600c1eefe7b5a71bf647803905b7e), [commit 27dc04c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/27dc04c54506967fcaa87b2d560547ee5633040c), [commit 13eeedb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/13eeedb5d17ca3539600b6618d103b652ecc8ab0), [commit c166599](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c166599862d10a273f61b834559eaa567c3dbfd9), [commit 37649b7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/37649b7f809f14b78d178c32e4d8333243f1f74e), [commit a2ce0a7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a2ce0a752600a44979da94b19aa1b367c6850bd7), [commit 50c817e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/50c817e0c02a133a1615ba32971fd5f6649c894f), [commit 9a3a0ff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a3a0ff5374f07d60eea01bbbe9a399d1f325280), [commit 0dab712](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0dab7129ab122d7ac5249fc7f6890302f29cd9e7), [commit 47edb64](https://github.com/git/git/commit/47edb649973cf5cd5f7066b5c936b330f78d687b) (14 Nov 2018), and [commit 2f90b9d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2f90b9d9b4ba1f8e79318853301e8ef19ca02681), [commit 1ccf07c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ccf07cbb762b44746c49634e1c6fb945c9977df) (22 Oct 2018) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 33e4ae9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33e4ae9c509e0ecdc6508475f2974d275539616e), 29 Jan 2019)</sup>

> ### Add a base implementation of SHA-256 support (Feb. 2019)

> SHA-1 is weak and we need to transition to a new hash function.
> For some time, we have referred to this new function as **`NewHash`**.
> Recently, we decided to **pick SHA-256 as `NewHash`**.
> [The reasons behind the choice of SHA-256 are outlined in this thread](https://public-inbox.org/git/20180609224913.GC38834@genre.crustytoothpaste.net/) and in the commit history for the hash function transition document.
>
> Add a basic implementation of SHA-256 based off **`libtomcrypt`**, which is in
> the public domain.
> Optimize it and restructure it to meet our coding standards.
> Pull in the update and final functions from the SHA-1 block implementation, as we know these function correctly with all compilers. This implementation is slower than SHA-1, but more performant implementations will be introduced in future commits.
>
> Wire up SHA-256 in the list of hash algorithms, and add a test that the
> algorithm works correctly.
>
> Note that with this patch, it is still not possible to switch to using SHA-256 in Git.
> Additional patches are needed to prepare the code to handle a larger hash algorithm and further test fixes are needed.

> ### `hash`: add an SHA-256 implementation using OpenSSL

> We already have OpenSSL routines available for SHA-1, so add routines
> for SHA-256 as well.
>
> On a Core i7-6600U, this SHA-256 implementation compares favorably to
> the SHA1DC SHA-1 implementation:
>
> ```
> SHA-1: 157 MiB/s (64 byte chunks); 337 MiB/s (16 KiB chunks)
> SHA-256: 165 MiB/s (64 byte chunks); 408 MiB/s (16 KiB chunks)
> ```

> ### `sha256`: add an SHA-256 implementation using `libgcrypt`

> Generally, one gets better performance out of cryptographic routines written in assembly than C, and this is also true for SHA-256.
> In addition, most Linux distributions cannot distribute Git linked against
> OpenSSL for licensing reasons.
>
> Most systems with GnuPG will also have `libgcrypt`, since it is a dependency of GnuPG.
> `libgcrypt` is also faster than the SHA1DC implementation for messages of a few KiB and larger.
>
> For comparison, on a Core i7-6600U, this implementation processes 16 KiB
> chunks at 355 MiB/s while SHA1DC processes equivalent chunks at 337
> MiB/s.
>
> In addition, `libgcrypt` is licensed under the LGPL 2.1, which is
> compatible with the GPL.  Add an implementation of SHA-256 that uses
> libgcrypt.

---

The upgrade effort goes on with Git 2.24 (Q4 2019)

See [commit aaa95df](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aaa95dfa051fc517dde0fa31187c744094cd17c5), [commit be8e172](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be8e172e9f4f62c9e4cdbecb5cd667775f38d4f1), [commit 3f34d70](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3f34d70d4029c420d0db82fc39e77da4470eb3cc), [commit fc06be3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fc06be3b7f065d197fd484098f517fa9d19c9d2b), [commit 69fa337](https://github.com/git/git/commit/69fa3370604e4410d845ff146ef86f8368e1ca79), [commit 3a4d7aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a4d7aa5aeeeb6c0b3d92cbaee0d32c2c956c72b), [commit e0cb7cd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0cb7cdb898d65bca6f1f4ff1d80f15a09b576db), [commit 8d4d86b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d4d86b0f0a875e7916d7de083a88d7f11251406), [commit f6ca67d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6ca67d673c66e5c3988a18c2ec56b7fef9a23b6), [commit dd336a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd336a55113a62789f039e382387d0407abaf922), [commit 894c0f6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/894c0f66bb21189d0677be6ecb9923b6acfbf437), [commit 4439c7a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4439c7a360a23c39e6dea3c9aae080c3c64eb6b6), [commit 95518fa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/95518faac1828d077de09b4049c9c4a6602c8ae2), [commit e84f357](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e84f3572bd9160f281629bb2a098b35ea87c10e1), [commit fe9fec4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fe9fec45f68e0d9850bf13da57b3e7a99fc33444), [commit 976ff7e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/976ff7e49d722d1b72effb6d547ec2b00cd69fc0), [commit 703d2d4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/703d2d4193738526d7b4116657657101e49a601e), [commit 9d958cc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d958cc0417ce2c8a4504ac8dd140685445ce4d7), [commit 7962e04](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7962e046ff2bfdeab1dad5c969dbd2b9209efe2f), [commit fee4930](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fee49308a1a6a3270a52b31275562f3e92f27d0a) (18 Aug 2019) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 676278f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/676278f8ea1b9bdd8f235eceb739d7aec4f0ed67), 11 Oct 2019)</sup>

> Instead of using `GIT_SHA1_HEXSZ` and hard-coded constants, switch to
> using `the_hash_algo`.

---

With Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), the **test scripts** are ready for the day when the object names will use SHA-256.

See [commit 277eb5a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/277eb5af7c83f0022a5c95a6d92dfe0c6072fc64), [commit 44b6c05](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44b6c05b43ccdcdd72623c4ce6b7fa7e816d8035), [commit 7a868c5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a868c51c2d1c43be6ad62f001edf581120c5b73), [commit 1b8f39f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b8f39fb0d2e9250a9867a6e498a33419ad7ab9f), [commit a8c17e3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a8c17e3bd6086bf3ed5c73fe610fc347ae494383), [commit 8320722](https://github.com/git/git/commit/832072219cf9f2607ac1a509510fc65cd2fe0e06), [commit 74ad99b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/74ad99b1d8e891623a523ead2097f628d78583d8), [commit ba1be1a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ba1be1ab45801db55e5b9e66194a82ffcc76b5f0), [commit cba472d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cba472d3adad06b07996c7d9df850c7e90a21ef3), [commit 82d5aeb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/82d5aeb1e606d6fb397d92c1b8ec95fd94b71d95), [commit 3c5e65c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3c5e65cac15a7f3a52fc53babd079aeaddb47c20), [commit 235d3cd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/235d3cddb8b0149a4ee339602386af24bfad620d), [commit 1d86c8f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1d86c8f0ce3471f0e8f2194dd821ffd292d79e3d), [commit 525a7f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/525a7f176980439fb1c32a34b705b06bcb7033f1), [commit 7a1bcb2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a1bcb251bf77ce76e19b54fc9ad85f8a4b92ee4), [commit cb78f4f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cb78f4f0fef7d45c33a22c28fcd575bed66a16d2), [commit 717c939](https://github.com/git/git/commit/717c939d8fe46638283a09e09d2b913974b4096d), [commit 08a9dd8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/08a9dd891c5808c2ab6e8b7fc5812e1f0cea1354), [commit 215b60b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/215b60bf079758405e4f396a2e68a00ec4d9e011), [commit 194264c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/194264c185515c67feed1972b735162c38054dbe) (21 Dec 2019) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f52ab33](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f52ab33616ee1d241f2292f1c1e47ba84a263523), 05 Feb 2020)</sup>

Example:

> ### [`t4204`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a1bcb251bf77ce76e19b54fc9ad85f8a4b92ee4): make hash size independent
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>

> Use `$OID_REGEX` instead of a hard-coded regular expression.

So, instead of using:

```
grep "^[a-f0-9]\{40\} $(git rev-parse HEAD)$" output
```

Tests are using

```
grep "^$OID_REGEX $(git rev-parse HEAD)$" output
```

And `OID_REGEX` comes from [commit bdee9cd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bdee9cd6c163d8b89a1ef87bbc09e394737df766) (13 May 2018) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9472b13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9472b13201aea57d7f9212ca2678aba4d6dbdfdb), 30 May 2018, Git v2.18.0-rc0)</sup>

> ### [`t/test-lib`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd981d5fc33677b4f074bac309ce64b39ba9d02e): introduce `OID_REGEX`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>

> Currently we have a variable, `$_x40,` which contains a regex that matches a full 40-character hex constant.
>
> However, with `NewHash`, we'll have object IDs that are longer than 40 characters.
>
> In such a case, `$_x40` will be a confusing name.
>
> Create a `$OID_REGEX` variable which will always reflect a regex matching the appropriate object ID, regardless of the length of the current hash.

And, still for tests:

See [commit f303765](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f3037657e8431073f0b240691877ca32baa142eb), [commit edf0424](https://github.com/git/git/commit/edf04243b2b805c4730c531745e8a5b317cd0a90), [commit 5db24dc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5db24dcffd8b6790ff4d9d73e13fa892ebc172a4), [commit d341e08](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d341e0805d91b4575ed3426be8e8bcb44744846c), [commit 88ed241](https://github.com/git/git/commit/88ed241a7eff7699a21c6868ef0682879f8a0dec), [commit 48c10cc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48c10cc0e6df1c916d00a661ee355817d82f30ca), [commit f7ae8e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7ae8e69b6540d6ec20208506b319a65161d4933), [commit e70649b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e70649bb664d4f3a4affa6bd4b663b1fcc8d6ac9), [commit a30f93b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a30f93b14378c285d936255b9749a1491765b9f6), [commit a79eec2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a79eec220b59a061cf94b3f3842ed7c20c13e579), [commit 796d138](https://github.com/git/git/commit/796d1383a395fb0eaf521b94d1305eb7fce3f579), [commit 417e45e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/417e45e5e38f824f65259f1c67d3a40b3597e12a), [commit dfa5f53](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dfa5f53e78ba80bb727a309ff90d7dbd83c7750c), [commit f743e8f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f743e8f5b35512f0e132e10df8f4519fdd4970d6), [commit 72f936b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/72f936b1206d807a2a252a71367a392001a83390), [commit 5df0f11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5df0f11f079fa83db8269f2d9818d93a240b115c), [commit 07877f3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/07877f393c9dbf96af606706475662259c6a3d57), [commit 6025e89](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6025e898d6271723ec1a0fac2c6b239592ed6b9e), [commit 7b1a182](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b1a1822fe4de212b486a0fbdcab0d03099e03dd), [commit 94db7e3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94db7e3e936ddc08c0a34c0c38cbee304a220c20), [commit db12505](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db12505c2c59f1e126e4bd79f80196510a7d30df) (07 Feb 2020) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5af345a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5af345a4388630b422a53fecfcc48b33e2439380), 17 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`t5703`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d341e0805d91b4575ed3426be8e8bcb44744846c): make test work with SHA-256
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>

> This test used an object ID which was 40 hex characters in length, causing the test not only not to pass, but to hang, when run with SHA-256 as the hash.
>
> Change this value to a fixed dummy object ID using `test_oid_init` and `test_oid`.
>
> Furthermore, ensure we extract an object ID of the appropriate length using cut with fields instead of a fixed length.

---

Some codepaths were given a repository instance as a parameter to work in the repository, but passed `the_repository` instance to its callees, which has been cleaned up (somewhat) with Git 2.26 (Q1 2020).

See [commit b98d188](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b98d18858187eb926912d5199533a6d2a14d5007), [commit 2dcde20](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2dcde20e1c55fc2e3f9e9e6d48e93c39ec5661d2), [commit 7ad5c44](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7ad5c44d9ce559703245d389aa71c4445dc9359c), [commit c8123e7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c8123e72f6d8bc4106afdd172895a28b0c30fb3b), [commit 5ec9b8a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5ec9b8accd6591641115d692fe2e9c4b88019d97), [commit a651946](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a6519467304dacb356da8a6c471d735ee6e846a4), [commit eb999b3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb999b3295b22680a41c0d807a8b442407b1b19f) (30 Jan 2020) by [Matheus Tavares (`matheustavares`)](https://github.com/matheustavares).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 78e67cd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/78e67cda42a440f216fc4cbfd8a9e190c5eece5a), 14 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`sha1-file`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b98d18858187eb926912d5199533a6d2a14d5007): allow `check_object_signature()` to handle any repo
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Matheus Tavares</sup>

> Some callers of `check_object_signature()` can work on arbitrary repositories, but the repo does not get passed to this function. Instead, `the_repository` is always used internally.
> To fix possible inconsistencies, allow the function to receive a struct repository and make those callers pass on the repo being handled.

Based on:

> ### [`sha1-file`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2dcde20e1c55fc2e3f9e9e6d48e93c39ec5661d2): pass `git_hash_algo` to `hash_object_file()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Matheus Tavares</sup>

> Allow `hash_object_file()` to work on arbitrary repos by introducing a `git_hash_algo` parameter. Change callers which have a struct repository pointer in their scope to pass on the `git_hash_algo` from the said repo.
> For all other callers, pass on `the_hash_algo`, which was already being used internally at `hash_object_file()`.
> This functionality will be used in the following patch to make `check_object_signature()` be able to work on arbitrary repos (which, in turn, will be used to fix an inconsistency at [`object.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2dcde20e1c55fc2e3f9e9e6d48e93c39ec5661d2/object.c):parse_object()).

---

Git 2.38 (Q3 2022) adds support for `libnettle`, as SHA256 implementation has been added.

See [commit e555735](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e55573583685eda80dd33d85ab2cea59b86332c5) (10 Jul 2022) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4af2138](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4af213841777a20636cc10d4de0da8d94796b141), 18 Jul 2022)</sup>

> ### [`sha256`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e55573583685eda80dd33d85ab2cea59b86332c5): add support for Nettle
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>

> For SHA-256, we currently have support for OpenSSL and libgcrypt because these two libraries contain optimized implementations that can take advantage of native processor instructions.
>
> However:
>
> - OpenSSL is not suitable for linking against for Linux distros due to licensing incompatibilities with the GPLv2, and
> - `libgcrypt` has been less favored by cryptographers due to some security-related implementation issues, which, while not affecting our use of hash algorithms, has affected its reputation.
>
> Let's add another option that's compatible with the GPLv2, which is **[Nettle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nettle_(cryptographic_library))**.
> This is an option which is generally better than `libgcrypt` because on many distros GnuTLS (which uses Nettle) is used for HTTPS and therefore as a practical matter it will be available on most systems.
> As a result, prefer it over `libgcrypt` and our built-in implementation.
>
> Nettle also has recently gained support for Intel's SHA-NI instructions, which compare very favorably to other implementations, as well as assembly implementations for when SHA-NI is not available.
>
> A [`git gc`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e55573583685eda80dd33d85ab2cea59b86332c5/Documentation/git-gc.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc))</sup> on [git.git](https://github.com/git/git) sees a 12% performance improvement with Nettle over our block SHA-256 implementation due to general assembly improvements.
> With SHA-NI, the performance of raw SHA-256 on a 2 GiB file goes from 7.296 seconds with block SHA-256 to 1.523 seconds with Nettle.

Comment: Plus, don't forget that Git v2.13.0 and later subsequently moved to a hardened SHA-1 implementation by default, which isn't vulnerable to the SHAttered attack. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43355918/6309

Comment: 1: Google produced collision https://shattered.io/ in Feb. 2017 (estimated cost $110,000)  
2: Nanyang Technological University produced a collision https://sha-mbles.github.io/  in Jan. 2019 (estimated cost between $11k - $45k)

It is time for Git to move past SHA1

Comment: @bristweb "It is time for Git to move past SHA1": I agree, and with Git 2.25 (released today), that move goes one. `git rev-parse` is now able to print what hash will be used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58862319/6309. And the empty tree has a new SHA2 id: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9766506/6309

Answer (score 54):

**UPDATE**: The above question and this answer are from 2015. Since then Google have announced the first SHA-1 collision: https://security.googleblog.com/2017/02/announcing-first-sha1-collision.html

---

Obviously I can only speculate from the outside looking in about why Git continues to use SHA-1, but these may be among the reasons:

1. Git was Linus Torvald's creation, and Linus apparently does not want to substitute SHA-1 with another hashing algorithm at this time.
2. He makes plausible claims that successful SHA-1 collision-based attacks against Git are a good deal harder than achieving the collisions themselves, and considering that SHA-1 is weaker than it should be, not completely broken, that makes it substantially far from a workable attack at least today. Moreover, he notes that a "successful" attack would achieve very little if the colliding object arrives later than the existing one, as the later one would just be assumed to be the same as the valid one and ignored (though others have pointed out that the reverse could occur).
3. Changing software is time-consuming and error-prone especially when there is existing infrastructure and data based around the existing protocols that will have to be migrated. Even those who produce software and hardware products where cryptographic security is the sole point of the system are still in the process of migrating away from SHA-1 and other weak algorithms in places. Just imagine all those hardcoded `unsigned char[20]` buffers all over the place ;-), it's a lot easier to program for cryptographic agility at the start, rather than retrofitting it later.
4. Performance of SHA-1 is better than the various SHA-2 hashes (probably not by so much as to be a deal-breaker now, but maybe was a sticking point 10 years ago), and the storage size of SHA-2 is larger.

Some links:

- [Stackoverflow question on what would happen if a collision did occur in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392365/how-would-git-handle-a-sha-1-collision-on-a-blob)
- [Newsgroup post showing a brief comment from Linus on the subject a couple of months after the main SHA-1 weakness became known in 2005](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/git.html)
- [A thread discussing the weakness and possible move to sha-256 (with replies from Linus) in 2006](http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/archives/git/0608/26427.html)
- [NIST statement on SHA-1 deprecation and recommending "to transition rapidly to the stronger SHA-2 family of hash functions"](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/statement.html)

My personal view would be that whilst practical attacks are probably some time off, and even when they do occur people will probably initially mitigate against them with means other than changing the hash algorithm itself, that if you do care about security that you should be erring on the side of caution with your choices of algorithms, and continually revising upwards your security strengths, because the capabilities of attackers are also going only in one direction, so it would be unwise to take Git as a role model, especially as its purpose in using SHA-1 is not purporting to be cryptographic security.

Comment: "You can have people who try to be malicious. They won't succeed. N̶o̶b̶o̶d̶y̶ ̶h̶a̶s̶ ̶b̶e̶e̶n̶ ̶a̶b̶l̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶b̶r̶e̶a̶k̶ ̶S̶H̶A̶-̶1̶, but the point is the SHA-1, as far as Git is concerned, isn't even a security feature. It's purely a consistency check." -Linus Torvalds

Comment: Git's hashes need to be secure for the secure signatures people place on their code to verify anything.  These signatures sign a huge tree of these hashes.  If some branch of that tree collides, malicious code can be inserted while the signature passes.  Git is used incredibly widely now.  A hash upgrade is needed.

Comment: Two things to consider in the light of "shattered":

 1. SHA-1 use.
     - SHA-1 is used as a glorified checksum to check against accidental corruption.
     - SHA-1 is used as a generator function to give a (somewhat small) handy hex number to designate objects inside its content addressable store (i.e.: glorified file-name generator).
     - It's *signed commits* which are responsible for security (i.e.:  public-key cryptography siganture. NOT sha-1)

Comment: 2. Feasibility
    - after tons of GPU time, Google has managed to generate a pair of block series.
    - both hash to the same SHA-1 sum (that's the collision)
    - they are completely rubish (that's going to be *hard* to justify why your commit has a a giant block of binary junk in the middle).
    - the shattered demo relies on having a way to present different behaviour depending on which of the random binary junk is present. That's possible with PDF (which has an embed scripting language hidden behind). That's going to be much harder on plain source (think Underhanded C Contest)

Comment: @DrYak For 2: let’s assume that you’re tracking photoshop documents with a comment field in them. Or other media files with meta tags. That’s a typical case in game development. But they won’t typically be checked on every change: why check the meta-tag if the commit message says "optimize for size"?

Comment: _"Linus apparently does not want to substitute SHA-1 with another hashing algorithm at this time"_ - Junio Hamano has been the lead of the project since late 2005, not Linus.

Answer (score 5):

This is a discussion of the urgency of migrating away from SHA1 for Mercurial, but it applies to Git as well: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/mpm/SHA1

In short: If you’re not extremely dilligent today, you have much worse vulnerabilities than sha1. But despite that, Mercurial started over 10 years ago to prepare for migrating away from sha1.

> work has been underway for years to retrofit Mercurial's data structures and protocols for SHA1's successors. Storage space was allocated for larger hashes in our revlog structure over 10 years ago in Mercurial 0.9 with the the introduction of RevlogNG. The bundle2 format introduced more recently supports the exchange of different hash types over the network. The only remaining pieces are choice of a replacement function and choosing a backwards-compatibility strategy.

If git does not migrate away from sha1 before Mercurial does, you could always add another level of security by keeping a local Mercurial mirror with [hg-git](http://hg-git.github.io/).

Answer (score 4):

There is now a [transition plan](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/technical/hash-function-transition.html) to a stronger hash, so it looks like in future it will use a more modern hash than SHA-1. From the [current transition plan](https://github.com/git/git/blob/752414ae4310cd304f5e31649aaab2dcf307057c/Documentation/technical/hash-function-transition.txt):

> Some hashes under consideration are SHA-256, SHA-512/256, SHA-256x16, K12, and BLAKE2bp-256