# How to get the raw content of a file through GitLab REST API?

Tags: git, rest, gitlab

The following REST Url of GitLab API gives me the repository tree of a project.

**Get Repo Tree (WORKS)**

```
https://gitlab.gspt.net/api/v3/projects/2931/repository/tree?private_token=XXXX
```

**Output:**

```
[
    {
        "id": "a49d11794ed56db7f935abfd61002aef67159d10",
        "name": "src",
        "type": "tree",
        "path": "src",
        "mode": "040000"
    },
    {
        "id": "0fbd98527d4b36e3d22c164293d8fd8eee4d18cd",
        "name": ".gitignore",
        "type": "blob",
        "path": ".gitignore",
        "mode": "100644"
    },
    {
        "id": "0ef0da472176f2e6a24843ac9d4bb738c8310d23",
        "name": "pom.xml",
        "type": "blob",
        "path": "pom.xml",
        "mode": "100644"
    }
]
```

But I am not able to get the raw content of a file, pom.xml to be precise.

**Get Raw Content of a file (DOES NOT WORK - Gives 404)**

```
https://gitlab.gspt.net/api/v3/projects/2931/repository/files/pom%2Exml/raw?private_token=xxxx&ref_name=master
```

Output:

```
{
    "error": "404 Not Found"
}
```

As per the documentation here (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-raw-file-from-repository) I am specify the correct rest url. The only thing that's different however is the use of V4 instead of V3 in the rest api endpoint. I searched around but could not find the endpoint of v3 api.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, just in case, don't percent encode the ".":

```
.../files/pom.xml/raw?...
            ^^
```

Second, you can check how the files endpoint was affected from v3 to v4 in the [merge request 9637](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/9637) and [this comparison](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/9637/diffs?diff_id=3247354&start_sha=197ee0e87a60832ae47fe8ebdc1e16ef77ea5f31)

```
v3:
GET /projects/:id/repository/raw_blobs/:sha
v4:
GET /projects/:id/repository/blobs/:sha/raw
```

You can see the examples (in v3) did not percent encode the dot.

```
curl --request GET --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK' \
  'https://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/projects/13083/repository/files?file_path=app/models/key.rb&ref=master'
```

However, the v3 API only allows to get raw blobs, not a raw file.
See [merge request 16834](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/16834):

> - Modify `/projects/:id/repository/files` to `/projects/:id/repository/files/:filepath` (`:filepath` should be URL-encoded)
> - Move `/projects/:id/repository/blobs/:sha` to `/projects/:id/repository/files/:filepath/raw`

Only v4 API allows for a `:filepath` parameters.

See "[Git objects SHA-1 are file contents or file names?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44476323/6309)" to decode the raw blob you get from API v3.

Comment: Thanks a lot Von, I got the content of the file using this url: `https://gitlab.gspt.net/api/v3/projects/2931/repository/files?file_path=pom.xml&ref=master`. However, the content of the file is encoded. How to get the raw content ?

Comment: @user2325154 By using the `/projects/:id/repository/raw_blobs/:sha` syntax I mention in the answer: see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/9637/diffs#4d37e90ff02b5014b4a2fda7e01b5c67fb686c11_96_96

Comment: Not sure what to specify in the `:sha`. Is `:sha` the commit-id of the file? I looked into the link you provided but it does not mention anything on how to get the raw content of the file. The content that I am getting from the above-mentioned url is `base64` encoded. I can always decode that and get the actual raw content of the file. But is there a way to get the raw content of the file directly?

Comment: @user2325154 Looking once more at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/9637/diffs#4d37e90ff02b5014b4a2fda7e01b5c67fb686c11_96_96, I don't see a syntax for raw file content in v3. It seems it has been added for v4 only for answering https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/16834: I have edited the answer accordingly, including a link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44476323/6309) to decode the raw blob. So: "is there a way to get the raw content of the file directly": not in v3.. Only in v4.

Answer (score 0):

Attention
dot(.) encode version:
see
[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Character_data)

```
  . == %2E
```